# How does "exports" from Eloquent JavaScript work?

Tags: javascript, module

I found this code I couldn’t understand from [this passage of Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#c_qHa2RFvopi):

```
(function(exports) {
    var names = [" Sunday ", " Monday ", " Tuesday ", " Wednesday ",
                " Thursday ", " Friday ", " Saturday "];
    exports.name = function(number) {
        return names[number];
    };
    exports.number = function ( name ) {
        return names.indexOf ( name );
    };
})(this.weekDay = {});

console.log(weekDay.name(weekDay.number("Saturday")));
```

In particular, I can't understand `this.weekDay`: what is `this` here?
And how we access the `weekDay.name`—it is in the function's scope, so how we have access to it out of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In global scope, `this` refers to the global object (which is `window` in web browsers and `global` in Node.js). So in this case, the assignment `this.weekDay = {}` is equivalent to `window.weekDay = {}` or just `weekDay = {}`, all of which create a global variable named `weekDay`. The nice thing about using `this` instead of `window` is that you can use the same notation for both browsers and Node. The references to `weekDay` below the module definition simply refer to the global `weekDay` variable; they could have been written as `this.weekDay` or `window.weekDay` as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

`weekDay` is *not* accessed in the function scope shown; `exports` is.

The new *object* assigned to `weekDay` (ie. `this.weekDay = {}`) is supplied as an argument to the IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression); and thus modifying the object (via `exports`) inside the function affects the same object elsewhere ..

.. and this object is known as `weekDay` (the global variable) in the calling scope, due to the original assignment.

```
(function ( exports ) {
  // in function
})( this.weekDay = {} );  // <-- not in function, 'this.' is superfluous
```